# Firebase message failed

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a xamarin android app and I want to add notifications.  I followed the instructions from this link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/

Everything worked great until I got to the Implement Client App Code section.  At first, when I clicked the button to get the InstanceId token, I didn't get anything.  So I added the bit of code that shows the google_app_id.  Mine does not match the mobilesdk_app_id value in the json file.  But then I did get an InstanceId in the output.  I used that id in the firebase console and the message fails, "Unregistered registration token".  I followed the directions exactly, twice.  And searched for the error but did not find any answers.  I guess my token is wrong?  How do I fix that?

Comment: Check logcat for `FirebaseInitProvider` tags and do any of them say `FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful` or `FirebaseApp initialization successful`

Comment: Try to uninstall app, after that install it again and try again to send message

Comment: @SushiHangover and dmitriy-kaluzhin, thanks for the replies.  I forgot to mention that I am using visual studio and xamarin for this project.  I don't even know what logcat is. :( But I looked at the output and didn't find anything that says "FirebaseInitProvider".  I did put a break point in the OnTokenRefresh code, and that produced a new token when I uninstalled and then reinstalled the app. But I still get the same error when I try to send a message to a single device from Firebase.  I guess for some reason the generated token is not being registered with firebase?

Comment: @user3302938 logcat : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Comment: @user3302938 If your service is executing `OnTokenRefresh` then you have the token needed to send a message to a single device via the Firebase console (i.e. that token is 150/153(?) characters long)

Comment: I did get a token OnTokenRefresh, but when I tried to send a message from the firebase web site to that specific token, I got the error mentioned above.  Never got it to work and abandoned the whole firebase method.  I have my own local web server and I can just set this up using signalr.  Initially, I thought it would be quick and easy to use firebase, and I wanted to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same tutorial and received the same error in the firebase console.  My problem turned out to be my android emulator configuration.

In the Android Virtual Device Manager I had to set my device's Target to **Google APIs**

I also had to install **Google Play services** from the Android SDK Manager

Lastly, I uninstalled my app on the emulator and reinstalled it to refresh the token.

After these steps i was able to send push notifications from the firebase console.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx78vrELgXk) helped me out.